# Sympy: Is it possible use function collect() to IndexedBase variables?

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

I'm trying to use the function **collect()** to simplify mi expression [image]. My desired result is [image]

My code:

```
from sympy import *

#index
i = symbols('i' , integer = True ) 

#constants
a = symbols( 'a' ) 

#variables
alpha = IndexedBase('alpha', positive=True, domain=QQ)

index = (i, 1, 3) 
rho = symbols( 'rho')
U = product( alpha[i]**(1/(rho-1)) , index )

U
```

:[image]

My solution attempt:

```
U = U.subs(1/(rho-1),a)
collect(U,rho, evaluate=False)[1]
```

:[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You must be using a fairly old version of SymPy because in recent versions the form that you wanted arises automatically. In any case you should be able to use `powsimp`:

```
In [9]: U
Out[9]: 
        a         a         a
alpha[1] ⋅alpha[2] ⋅alpha[3] 

In [10]: powsimp(U, force=True)
Out[10]: 
                            a
(alpha[1]⋅alpha[2]⋅alpha[3])
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/simplification.html#powsimp